Serializing default Enum variant into json with serde_json renders null
I'm trying to serialize a struct which has some Optional enum fields to their default enum variants.
By default I mean the variant marked with the #[default] serde attribute. However, this keeps on deserialising to null instead of the default value.
Here's a simple example
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json;

#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    pub text: String,
    #[serde(default)]
    pub version: Option<Version>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Deserialize, Serialize, Default)]
pub enum Version {
    #[serde(rename = "PlayV1.0")]
    PlayV1,
    #[serde(rename = "PlayV2.0")]
    #[default]
    PlayV2,
}

fn main() {
    let req = Foo {
        text: "Hello, world!".to_string(),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let json = serde_json::to_string(&req).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);
}

I have tried omitting the derive(Default) from the enum and instead, implementing my own e.g.
impl Default for Version {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Version::PlayV2
    }
}

However I still get the following json
{"text":"Hello, world!","version":null}

What I'd like is this:
{"text":"Hello, world!","version": "PlayV2.0"}

I'm sure I'm missing something here or maybe this simply isn't even possible.

The serde default attribute will change nothing when serializing, it only has an effect when deserializing.


I have tried omitting the derive(Default) from the enum and instead, implementing my own e.g.

That's the wrong default: Foo::default() will invoke Option::default() which is None. So if you want to override the default value for the version field you need to either remove the Option so that the derived Foo::default calls Version::default, or impl Default for Foo by hand.

@ChayimFriedman I guess that's an interpretation of the post, but I didn't even think of such a convoluted scheme, from the example code I'd assume they want to default the field in general.

Ok, this is interesting. I've updated my question with a sample that works as pers your suggestion @Masklinn

@ChayimFriedman ok, this is interesting, but I think I'll pass on that and will go with Masklinn's suggestion, but I'll defo try it out. the issue is, with a lot of Optional enums that's a lot of typing

Ah, I missed that they want serialization, not deserialization.

@ChayimFriedman well, I think I'll need deser at some point as well, actually. Your suggestion was to do an impl on the Option field before you deleted it?

@milosgajdos If you need to deserialize with default values, what I suggested was either a newtype wrapper or #[serde(deserialize_as)].

Moved here from the question:

So here's something that works as per Masklinn suggestion
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    pub text: String,
    #[serde(default)]
    pub version: Option<Version>,
}

impl Default for Foo {
    fn default() -> Self {
        return Foo {
            text: "".to_owned(),
            version: Some(Version::default()),
        };
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Deserialize, Serialize, Default)]
pub enum Version {
    #[serde(rename = "PlayV1.0")]
    PlayV1,
    #[serde(rename = "PlayV2.0")]
    #[default]
    PlayV2,
}

fn main() {
    let req = Foo {
        text: "Hello, world!".to_string(),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let json = serde_json::to_string(&req).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);
}


